# Python - node-based collection memory allocation

Tags: python, memory, memory-management

This is broken up into 2 questions. I do also want to throw out there that these questions arise out of sheer curiosity.

**Question 1**
What would be the method on going about retrieving the memory of a node-based collection? I.e. how much memory is a node chain taking up? If you wanted to find the amount of memory a list takes up you'd use:

```
import sys
sys.getsizeof([])
```

When I use the same command on my collection class (see below), `sys.getsizeof(DoublyLinkedBag())`, it gives me a value 56. However, when I add in a node and run the same command, I'll get the same number. I'm assuming this is because I'm getting the allocation of the class instance and not the allocation of the node chain.

I also tried doing `sys.getsizeof(node.add(3))`. Going off of the presumption stated above, would I add the value it gives me times the size of the node chain to the value `sys.getsizeof(DoublyLinkedBag())` gives me?

Associated doubly linked class:

```
class DoublyLinkedBag:

    class Node:
        def __init__(self, element = None):
            self.next = None
            self.prev = None
            self.element = element

    def __init__(self):
        self.front = None
        self.rear = None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self, element):

        n = self._make_new_node(element)

        if self.size == 0:
            self.front = self.rear = n
            self.size += 1
        else:
            n.prev = self.rear
            self.rear.next = self.rear = n
            self.size += 1

    # contains, removes methods here...

# add nodes
node = DoublyLinkedBag()
node.add(4)
node.add(6)
```

**Question 2**
Are the nodes stored in heap or stack memory, and why? I've tried to reason through this myself, but I find myself hopping between the two answers.

Comment: `node.add` returns `None`, so you don't want to "add the value it gives you times the size of the node chain to the value", because... why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate memory allocation I would suggest trying with [asizeof](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/asizeof.html) from pympler lib.

```
from pympler import asizeof

...

bag = DoublyLinkedBag()

for i in range(100):
    print(asizeof.asizeof(bag))
    bag.add(i)
```